# Route all traffic via OpenVPN client

Tags: windows, routing, openvpn

I've got OpenVPN client running on 192.168.0.3. What I'd like to do is route all the traffic from the second computer with 192.168.0.100 via OpenVPN client that's running on the first computer.
My router ip is 192.168.0.1

Network topology:

```
Windows computer with OpenVPN client: 192.168.0.3
Windows computer whose traffic has to be rerouted: 192.168.0.100
Router: 192.168.0.1
```

I want it to work in the following way:

```
192.168.0.100 computer => 192.168.0.3 computer => OpenVPN => 192.168.0.1
```

How can I achieve that by only modifying windows' routing table?
I've tried entering the following into windows shell(on computer without VPN), which didn't work (it just dropped my internet connection):

```
route delete 0.0.0.0 mask 255.255.255.255 192.168.0.1
route add 0.0.0.0 mask 255.255.255.255 192.168.0.3
```

Should I also setup the computer that has OpenVPN client running?

Does it have anything to do with windows tcp forwarding?

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you just setup an VPN connection to OpenVPN from 192.168.0.100 ?

Comment: Because that's an OpenVPN client that's installed on 192.168.0.3, it's not a server. Only 192.168.0.3 should connect to the internet and I want it to act as sort of a proxy. I was able to achieve what I want by installing an http proxy service on 192.168.0.3, however I want not only http to be forwarded - I want all of the traffic to be forwarded.

Comment: Any suggestions? Does it have to do anything with "TCP forwarding" on windows?

Comment: You could use ICS.